# how to transfer folder from linux machine to windows

Tags: linux, remote-access, pscp

please suggest possible solution to transfer folder from Linux machine to windows machine.
I have tried below command using PSCP but couldn't achieve anything.

```
 pscp -pw abc123 10.11.23.123:/opter/ss/* c:/user/other/
```

But I could see fatal error & connection timed out.
please suggest other option rather than pscp if available to transfer folder from Linux to windows
Note: server is working fine

Comment: If the machines are on the same LAN and can see each other, `xcopy /s /i \\linuxmachine\path\to\dir dir` works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this I have achieved the output
pscp -pw password username@ipaddress:/* "C:\"